# Migrating Core Data related code to Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest, xcode7

I have some functions like this:

```
func getAllEntities() -> [MyEntity]? {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"MyEntity")

    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [MyEntity]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        return results
    }
    else {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

And now with the upgrade to `Swift 2` and `Xcode 7`, I get errors like these:

> Cannot downcast from '[AnyObject]' to a more optional type '[MyEntity]?'
>
> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

This is after having performed the automatic `Swift` code migration you are asked to do when you first start `Xcode 7`. What is the correct way to re-write my function in the new `Swift` version?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I need to keep backwards compatibility with `iOS 7` and `iOS 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors:

- In Swift 2,  `executeFetchRequest()` returns a non-optional. So you cannot cast the return value to `[MyEntity]?`. You can (forced or optionally) cast it to `[MyEntity]`.
- `executeFetchRequest()` throws an error in the error case, so it must
  be called with `try` inside a `do-catch` statement.

Example:

```
func getAllEntities() -> [MyEntity]? {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [MyEntity]
        return results
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

A forced cast `as! [MyEntity]` is acceptable here (as in your
original code) because you *know* the class for the entity, it is
set in the Core Data model inspector.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I need to keep my app compatible with iOS 7 & 8, and it seems that Swift 2 is only available for iOS 8 and above... I edited my question. How could I handle that?

Comment: @AppsDev: As far as I know, Swift 2 deploys back to iOS 7, so that should not be a problem. – It is *not* possible to write code that compiles with both Swift 1.2 and Swift 2, these version are too different.

Comment: Xcode help shows that the new `executeFetchRequest` is available for iOS 8.1 and above

Comment: @AppsDev: executeFetchRequest is available since iOS 3 (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/executeFetchRequest:error:). There is no "new" executeFetchRequest, only the mapping to Swift is different between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2. The above code compiles without problems with iOS 7 deployment target in my Xcode 7GM. I will double-check with the final version as soon as I have downloaded it.

Comment: @AppsDev: The above code compiles with Xcode 7 and deployment target set to iOS 7.The availability notice in the Xcode help inspector is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question, my project mixes `Objective-C` and `Swift` and now looks like `Swift` code is not accesible from `Objective-C` classes anymore... do you know something about this?

Comment: @AppsDev: That should generally still be possible, so much more information is needed. I would suggest to post a new question with all relevant information. – Btw, the "availability" in the help inspector is wrong even for simple methods like "viewDidLoad". I have posted a question in the Apple Developer Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18318.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, I usually get suggestions from Xcode, typically asking me to lose the ? or change it to !, I can't offer you a concrete solution.

This is the code to solve the second error:

```
func getAllEntities() -> [MyEntity]? {

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"MyEntity")

var error: NSError?
let fetchedResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [MyEntity]?

do {
return results
}

catch error {
print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
}

return nil
}
```